# RuntimeError: unexpectedly data truncated Error Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've then  been having this error  whenever the show and Edit action of a Controller is called :, Just did an upgrade of an App to 3.1 from 3.0.10, but i doubt if the problem is related to the upgrade as other Controllers work as expected. Im Using MySQL

```
RuntimeError: unexpectedly data truncated:SELECT  `courses`.* FROM `courses`  WHERE `courses`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1
```

My Controller's Edit and show actions

```
def edit
...
@course = Course.find(params[:id])
@title = "#{@course.name}'s Details"
...
end

def show
...
@title = "Course Detail"
@course = Course.find(params[:id])
...
end
```

And the a view

```
 <%= form_for @course do |f|%>
      <%= render 'form' ,:f => f%>
      <%= f.submit :class=> "btn " %>
      <%= link_to "Delete User" , @course, :method =>:delete,:confirm =>"You Sure?",
                  :title => "Delete #{@course.email}",:class => "btn " %>
      <%= link_to 'Cancel', courses_path,:class => "btn" %>
 <% end %>
```

Have little clue as to the Source of the error

EDIT

```
create_table "courses", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "date"
t.string   "time"
t.string   "venue"
t.integer  "roomnumber"
t.string   "tutor"
t.string   "type"
t.string   "name"
t.string   "description"
t.string   "status"
t.string   "duration"
t.integer  "maxallowed"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Comment: I think we need more info. Can you edit the question and add the courses table section from schema.db so we can see how it is defined?

Answer (score 0):

This is coming from your Mysql driver because the data that you are attempting to set on one of your columns is longer than 255 characters (the default for t.string). You need to truncate the data yourself before_save or change the column type to text by declaring it as t.text. Only do this for fields that should be long though, as blob fields can become expensive.

Comment: Tried out with two character long string as input and still had same issues